# Why $\sqrt{\left(\frac{-\sqrt3}2\right)^2+{(\frac12)}^2}$ is equal to 1?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation, radicals

$\sqrt{\left(\frac{-\sqrt3}2\right)^2+{(\frac12)}^2}$

---

By maths calculator it results 1.
I calculate and results $\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

$\sqrt{\left(\frac{-\sqrt3}2\right)^2+{(\frac12)}^2}$

$\sqrt{\frac{-{(3)}^{{\displaystyle\frac12}\times2}}{2^2}+\frac{1^2}{2^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{-3}4+\frac14}=\sqrt{\frac{-3+1}4}=\sqrt{\frac{-2}4}=\sqrt{-\frac12}$

Enlighten me what went wrong?

Comment: $(-\sqrt{3})^2=\sqrt{3}^2=3$

Comment: $(-\sqrt{3})^2=(-1)^2(3)^{{\frac{1}{2}}2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$(-\sqrt{3})^2=(-1)^2(3)^{{\frac{1}{2}}2}=3$

Comment: I selected your answer as answer because my level of understanding matches your explanation. Other answers are also helpful but I stuck thinking about their answers.

Comment: @Nay Sie thank you very much I wish you success

Answer (score 6):

The square of a negative number is positive.

$$\left(-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you very much for time and answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's something called the "Trivial Inequality" that states $$x^2 \geq 0$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. So $$\left( -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you very much for time and answer.

Comment: @NaySie Thank you very much. Have a great day. :)

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{\left(\frac{-\sqrt3}2\right)^2+{(\frac12)}^2}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}+{\frac14}}=\sqrt{1}=1.$ 
Your problem was with not powering the minus in the first expression in numerator.
See the difference between $$(-\sqrt3)^2=3$$ and  $$-(\sqrt3)^2=-3.$$ As you can see in the first case the minus is inside the brackets which means that the minus has to be raised to the power (opposite situation we have in the second case).